# Submit button in modal is not functioning to open another modal

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my HTML code for the first modal. The submit button is not functioning to open another modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="newModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">New record</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
                       aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" 
                           placeholder="Input name of client">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" onclick="submitForm()" class="btn 
                     btn-primary">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-
           dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is the HTML code for the second modal when you click the submit button on the first one.

```
       <div class="modal fade" id="confirmationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form action="php/insert_client.php" method="post">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                 Are you sure you want to add this client?
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="validateForm()">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>  
</div>
```

This is the javascript for the newModal and confirmationModal

```
  function submitForm() {
      document.getElementById("newModal").submit();
   }

  function validateForm(e) {
        $("#confirmationModal").modal("show");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the JS code you've shown, this function will need to be called in order for your second modal to be displayed:

```
function validateForm(e) {
  $("#confirmationModal").modal("show");
}
```

Right now, it's not being called until the second modal's *Save* button is clicked.

Comment: its still not functioning. the submit button on the first is still not working

Comment: How did you update the code? Is there an error thrown?

Comment: Unless something's changed from the original HTML, `newModal` is a `div` not a `form` and won't have a `submit` method to invoke.

Comment: I enclose the two modal in form action. there's no error

Comment: Can you add the HTML that shows the form in the first modal? Right now, here's what I see: `<div class="modal fade" id="newModal">`. So in this case, you won't be able to invoke `submit` here. Also, since you've set the _Submit_ button's `type` to be `submit`, the page is going to refresh unless you prevent it from doing so in your click handler with something `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: <button type="button" onclick="submitForm()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>. I don't know if this is correct all I need to do is when clicking the submit button there will be a popup saying it is successfully added.

Comment: Ok, but in your second modal you've defined a `form` that is nested between your `div` with a class of `modal-dialog` and your `div` with a class of `modal-content`: `<form action="php/insert_client.php" method="post">`.

Comment: I've created a working JS Bin that you can take a look at: http://jsbin.com/doxahaqide/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: does it really affect my other modals? cause my two other modals for editing and deleting is not poping up already/

Comment: Yeah no worries. In a sense your modals will affect each other, especially the JS that will cause the next modal to appear. Just make sure that you're calling `.modal("show")` in the right place. For example, the reason the **second modal** wasn't appearing was because `.modal("show")` wasn't called as the **first modal** was closing. So if you wan't an **edit modal** to appear, you'll need a click handler with something like `document.getElementById("editModal").modal("show")`.

Comment: Shameless plug: since it appears the answer resolved your original question, when you get the chance can you please mark it as accepted?

Comment: and yes I already have this one.  function editModal(e) {
        $("#editModal").modal("show");

        focusedid = e;
        identifier = focusedid.split('-')[1];

        $("#editid").val( $("#id-" + identifier).val() );
        $("#editname").val( $("#name-" + identifier).val() );
    }

    function deleteModal(e) {
        $("#deleteModal ").modal("show");

        focusedid = e;
        identifier = focusedid.split('-')[1];

        $("#deleteid").val( $("#id-" + identifier).val() );
    }